# what's the error in posting this question although it is statistics based?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [Diagnostic Plots Doubt](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520613/diagnostic-plots-doubt)

Answer (score 8):

Closing the question follows the policy stated in wiki for the self-study tag.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

In summary, self-study questions are welcome, but we require the person asking to show what they've tried and where they're stuck. If you were to edit your question to include this information, it would be eligible for reopening.